# Beautiful Soup: extracting picture url from webpage

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So currently I'm having some issues trying to extract a picture URL from a web page using beautiful soup. I'm quite inexperienced with beautiful soup and would appreciate any feedback you have for me. Here is a snippet of the HTML I'm trying to extract the picture link from (more specifically, the data-srcset URL in the source media tag):

```
<div class="container-fluid" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <div class="row">
    <div id="js_carousel" class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
      <div id="psp-carousel" class="carousel_outer">
        <div id="product-carousel" class="pdp-carousel carousel pdp-initial" style="display:block;">
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <img class="product-image-placeholder" itemprop="image" alt="..." src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' viewBox%3D'0 0 355 462'%3E %3Crect fill%3D'%23eee' width%3D'100%25' height%3D'100%25'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" width="355" height="462">
            <picture class="item active" data-image="//s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/1162_8725_499_of" role="option" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
              <source media="(max-width: 767px)" data-srcset="//s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/1162_8725_499_of?$pdp-main_small$" srcset="//s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/aeo/1162_8725_499_of?$pdp-main_small$">
```

Any time I try to use the line 
`my_imgs = page_soup.findAll('picture',{'class':'item active'})`
I get an empty array. I apologize if this is a dumb question, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try findAll("picture", class_="item active")

Comment: Just tried that @Olllaw, it unfortunately returned an empty array as well :( Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `.select()` function for a bs4 instance?  The [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) says that this is the prefered method for finding css elements in your HTML soup.  So in this case use `page_soup.select('picture[class="item active"]')` instead of `.findall()` 
 The `.find()` and `.findAll()` are for older versions of Beautiful Soup.  And reading the documentation it seems like your code for the older versions should be formatted `my_imgs = page_soup.findAll('picture', attrs ={'class':'item active'})` instead of `my_imgs = page_soup.findAll('picture',{'class':'item active'})` you forgot to include the attrs part of the code to create a dictionary which beautiful soup then uses incase the data attributes that have names that can't be used as keyword arguments